# How can siphoning power from a god fail to increase Mana reserves?

Tags: technology, gods, machine-cult

Through magical rituals, entities can be summoned into our worlds and placed into avatars, humanoid shells serving as a container for their souls. A corporation has used this method to summon a god in order to entrap it within a custom-built machine called the agonizer linked to several generators. This is done to siphon mana from the god as a power source which can be used as a permanent supply of energy for society, comparable to an artificial sun. The company has essentially turned the god into a living battery, supplying them with an unlimited source of energy which can be collected through generators and sent to other facilities for processing. The machine is linked to the deity's nervous system, applying a continuous steam of pain to the god in order to release mana, which is then directed through the links connecting it to the generators. This leaves the entity completely at the mercy of its captors.

The mana released from the god is incredibly powerful and destructive, in unquantifiable large amounts.  Through trial and error, the corporation have discovered that their technology is too weak to contain the level of mana being siphoned. The energy output destroys the generators meant to collect it, as they cannot sustain the power from the rapid release. One solution was to lower the level of output coming from the deity, allowing them to extract the energy slower at a steadier pace. By lowering the level of man being received all at once, they can slowly build up the amount of mana being collected over a longer period of time. Although this would take longer, it would be more efficient and save them the cost of replacing destroyed equipment. However, slowing down the pace doesn't increase the amount of mana at all, insignificant of time period. The amount being produced is miniscule, making it useless as a form of energy.

The corporation has come to the conclusion that the only way to extract this energy is by releasing it at large amounts all at once like before, requiring them to build better generators capable of absorbing that level of power quickly and efficiently without being blown up. This will require significant expense and time, taking years to construct such devices, making it a huge investment. How can it be that a slow and steady, drawn-out method of extracting energy slowly won't lead to a buildup of energy?

Comment: Do you have any criteria for a better answer?

Answer (score 8):

### The god doesn't actually want to release a small and manageable amount of power.

They could certainly do so, and many religions rely on gods who do such for their religion, but this god is being tortured and abused for mana. They'll release it accidentally in fits of anger, but if the torture is reduced to a manageable level they'll focus on repairing their damaged soul instead, so they can survive and perhaps one day escape.

If they formed a consensual and honest relationship with the god they could release reasonable amounts of power, but they instead captured them and tortured them.

Comment: Or very similarly, they know are trapped so they release huge surges of power specifically trying to break free.

Comment: This manga pretty much writes itself.

Answer (score 2):

## [Helios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios) - To Burn Like The Sun:

You make the analogy of the imprisoned god putting out energy like an artificial sun. But the sun gets energy from nuclear fusion, and your god is outputting mana in a similar way. The god burns with the glory of the sun. Your corporation is trying to contain and channel the equivalent of a runaway fusion reaction. Like fusion power, it SOUNDS like a great idea, but the devil is in the details.

There is no "small output" when this kind of reaction is involved. The trickle of energy they obtain at the lower setting is more akin to radiation from a block of highly enriched uranium. While you can obtain power from this slow fission process, it's nowhere near what they need to power the entire civilization, and the cost to get it is higher than what it takes to obtain.

So until they build a housing and energy-transforming infrastructure capable of containing the equivalent of a small nuclear bomb going off, they aren't going to be able to exploit the capture of the god for profit.

Answer (score 2):

**The god is messing with them.**

It is actually not in pain.  It allowed itself to be "captured" and remains because it chooses to.  It is not actually being held or anything else by the various technosorcerous mechanisms in place.  It is putting out mana as it sees fit.  Its captors do not know any of this.

The god has other objectives that were easier to advance by this "capture" and while "captive" it is working on those.  On the side it is toying with its captors because that is amusing.

Comment: This makes the most sense to me.  A god isn't just a normal guy with way more power than the rest of us.  It is an eons old entity with an understanding of the universe which has allowed it to obtain that power and to participate as an intellectual equal in the communities of other gods.  If that god happens to be of the trickster variety, it might not even have another objective that it is pursuing.  It might just be setting up a cosmic level confidence game such that after the corps invest in their bigger and later even bigger generators, it flies away leaving them bankrupt and powerless.

Answer (score 1):

The system uses up the mana trying to extract it.  Only mana works, and it keeps using more than expected.   Everyone keeps thinking that this patch or that one will finally ensure that it doesn't eat its own extract,  but it never works.

Answer (score 0):

[Power density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_density) over energy density

Trying to use TNT as fuel for an internal combustion engine will result in the engine either performing poorly (if the TNT is burned) or utterly destroyed (if the TNT is detonated).

TNT is able to release an immense amount of power in a single burst - on the order of 10<sup>13</sup>W/m<sup>3</sup> - but the energy developed by slowly burning TNT (4.184MJ/kg) is just [10% of the energy of the same mass of gasoline (46.4MJ/kg)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#In_chemical_reactions_(oxidation)).

Answer (score 0):

### A Problem With Pressure

The god can release a massive amount of power, right? So the company has to build magical "circuits" that can withstand that much power. This is true for any magic system: the amount of power that any magic generator creates fluctuates randomly. Normally, this isn't a problem: the fluctuation is minimal, and so you only need to make a small change in the capacity of the circuit to make the system not overload. However, even a reduced draw from the god has far too much fluctuation for any small capacity change to work.

The company, then, must create a extremely high-capacity circuit that only SOMETIMES needs that much space; it usually only uses a tiny amount of that space. Now, imagine a giant water pipe, running perfectly straight. You need a massive amount of water pressure to push the water all the way through the pipe. Without enough water, their isn't enough pressure to push ANY water through the pipe, and it doesn't send water from one end of the pipe to the other. (Ever had a shower that just drops water straight down? That's because there isn't enough pressure to propel it out of the showerhead.)

Now, lets imagine that when in the wire, magic "evaporates", albeit slowly. Again, normally, this isn't a problem, because the wire is only a short step in the magic movement process. However, because of the incredibly low magic pressure, the magic takes too long in the circuit, and evaporates entirely before it reaches the end of the circuit.

Unless the god is fluctuating at its highest level, there isn't enough magic pressure to push the magic through the magic circuit before it evaporates, and so no magic makes it to the end. The generating process is, therefore, useless.

Answer (score 0):

Several factors to consider in this equation

**The Amount of Power Available to Extract**

Beyond whatever powers are attributed to a given God in mythology - magic, immortality, certainly most of the power available to any given God is based upon the number and strength of its religious followers. How many temples does this God have? What is the God's preferred form of offering and is this offering being supplied in sufficient quantity to please said God?

Realizing this, we are in truth converting energy from sacrificial offerings into mana. If the adherents to this God are dwindling and they are making less offerings then it logically follow the God will have less power available to drain. Are the quality and quantity of the offerings made to this God sufficient to power a large scale energy network? This also begs the question what happens if the religious offering finds out about it? I would imagine they'd launch a crusade if they realised they were in fact making offerings to this corporation's bottom line, and that the energy that might otherwise go towards bringing rain to their crops was powering some distant city. I think it would be clear even to the lowest priests in this following that the diety was in pain and task a hero with finding out why

If the amount of followers and temples are dwindling, the God would lose total power intake. If it grew, it would gain power, following the logic of that old argument: Is hell endothermic or exothermic?

**The limits of the mortal vessel**

Binding the deity to a mortal works well for making some part of the deity anchored to this world. Sending pain signals to the deity through this body to whatever realm it calls home would be complicated though because you need to keep the body healthy and alive. Too much pain over too long and the body will go into shock and die.

The usefulness of the host would also pretty much be exclusively limited to signals because a mortal body makes a very poor conductor of energy in any form, and trying to use one as a conductor for industrial strength power transmission is going to end with one very dead body. To recover any useful amount of energy you would need a different circuit to get power out.

**The amount of time you can hold a charge**

Mana could be pretty unstable stuff and difficult to store. It could dissipate or diffuse from areas of high concentration to areas of low concentration, following the path of least resistance -- a ley line in essence, like a river. In this world, it would need to be carefully confined and converted to some other form of energy quickly or it would find somewhere else to drain into. Containment sigils that work during a waxing or full moon might be less efficient during the waning / new moon for example. Alignments of the stars, other spiritual affairs can effect this.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Fundamental Misunderstanding/Misinterpretation of the Nature of Magic/Mana and Metaphysics**

Any Magical/Sci-Fi coexistance world ought to play into magical and scientific theories. Much like real life science such as consumption of lead in ancient times or using heroin to treat cough only a century ago or that humans once believed in geocentrism instead of heliocentrism. Many old scientific beliefs would not change unless something specific happens to prove them wrong.

You might devise specific metaphysical laws / theorums that the corporation got wrong.

2. **Contrary to the corporation's belief, the deity is *truly* a divine being tied to the creation and existence of the universe.**

Could be a bit cliche'd but the what even *is* a "deity" in your world? Perhaps your corporation believed magic is simply occult knowledge that is not yet studied and formalized into science. However, since the deity *truly* is the origin of all life, perhaps minor releases of power is immediately "evaporated" or "consumed" by the world around you, as the world naturally draws mana from her on a regular basis. She is the source of all life, afterall. Perhaps releasing small quantities if energy is something she *already does* to keep existence in tact.

Your corporation might ignore/reject that understanding and insist on extracting power anyway, and risk cessasion of all life itself.

3. **The technology required for different levels of extraction is different**, and the low-power setting malfucntioned, was sabotaged by a third party, is more difficult to control, gets destroyed by the power, etc.

I can't think of real life analogs off the top of my head but I'm sure there are plenty of IRL resources that extraction methods vary based on scale.

4. **Mana in your world can operate on different wavelength/frequencies** similar to voltages and radiowaves. The level for low extraction may be technologically incompatible.
5. **The deity is deceiving the corporation.** The deity may deliberately want to trick the corporation into going back to the high power setting and unleash its full might to overload and destroy the facility as a means to escape.